# Binding OneWay or OneTime

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a textblock that when the user is selected from a drop down the following `TextBlock` displays the "Name" of the user.  This works great!

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

However, on another part of the screen I a `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox  x:Name="newName" Text="{Binding Name}">
```

Which is editable and contains the same data.

So right now when a User is selected both elements gets populated but I want to prevent the `TextBlock` from being updated when the `TextBox` is updated.

Comment: Why don't you just leave the `Mode=OneWay` in the `TextBox` binding?

Comment: Sounds like it would be better to keep this logic in the view-model. Have an "InitialName" property, and bind the TextBlock to that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use "OneTime" binding mode on the textblock to get a snapshot of the data on init or context change.

-m